# Rails coffee render template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have lists in erb and form, when I add new list I want see new element without reload page

lists page

```
<p id='lists'>
 <%= render 'lists/lists', object: @user %>
</p>
```

I have lists  and when I add new list want reload tag by id, in js coffe 
 find class and render for my partial, but have error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: [stdin]:5:28: unexpected string):
1: 
2: $("#lists").prepend("<%= (render partial: "lists/lists")%>");
3: $('form')[0].reset()
```

Try another way

```
$("#lists").prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "lists/lists")%>");
```

have last list, but all list double in page

how to correct render partial for some id in coffee ?

Comment: Can you please show the content of your `lists/list` partial?

Answer (score 0):

Change `"double quotes"` to `'single'`

```
$("#lists").prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'lists/lists')%>");
```

This might be the issue